# List of generic<T> class instances - call function that takes T

Tags: kotlin, types

I have a class that looks like this:

```kotlin
class MyClass<T : BaseClass> {
    fun get(): T
    fun process(thing: T)
}
```

If I had a single instance of this class of type `X`, for example, I could do:

```kotlin
val instance: MyClass<X> = getInstance()
val t = instance.get()
t.foo = bar
instance.process(t)
```

However, instead of having just one, I have a list of them, each having a different type as `T`:

```kotlin
val list: List<MyClass<*>> = getInstances()
val t = list[0].get()
t.foo = bar
// Error here: type mismatch - BaseClass cannot be converted to Nothing
list[0].process(t)
```

That is because `MyClass<*>.get()` returns `BaseClass` and, in contrast, `MyClass<*>.process()` takes `Nothing` as its argument, so it cannot be called.

How can I call `process()` on one of the list members, with the result of `get()`?

So far, my solution is:

```kotlin
val t = list[0].get()
t.foo = bar
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
(list[0] as MyClass<BaseClass>).process(t)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply extract the piece of code where you need the `T` into a generic function (which kinda captures the actual generic type of `MyClass` for the body of your function):

```kotlin
fun <T> MyClass<T>.getAndProcess(foo: Foo) {
    val t = get()
    t.foo = foo
    process(t)
}
```

This way of extracting into a generic function basically allows you, like in math, to declare *"let `T` be the `T` of that `MyClass` instance"*.

Then you can call `getAndProcess()` on a `MyClass<*>` like this:

```kotlin
val list: List<MyClass<*>> = getInstances()
list[0].getAndProcess(foo = bar)
```

Comment: Great answer! Although, my bad, I worded the question wrongly. I need the result from `get()`, and `get()` cannot be called twice.

Comment: This is fine, you can tweak the extracted function. I updated the body. You can also make it return `t` (of type `T`) although you won't see the exact type `T` outside `getAndProcess()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's actually a bit difficult to implement this, as `process(t)` is actually Composable, so my getAndProcess() will receive a `@Composable (BaseClass) -> Unit` argument, and I'll wrap all the code that needs access to `t` in the lambda.

Comment: Go it, yeah if `process` doesn't need the exact `T` but just the base class, you can indeed just put it outside. Anyway it seems you can take it from here. If your use case gets more complicated feel free to open a new question or edit this one